# How do we write the command in Pidgin ALGOL?

Tags: algorithm, algol

How can we write the command: `printf("%d->%d", X, Y);` in ALGOL where X and Y are the arguments of the recursive function.

Do we have to write something like: `write "X -> Y";` ?

Or can we write : `write "%d -> %d, X, Y";`

Answer (score 0):

The question is probably more philosophical that you intended, as Algol (60) did not contain any input/output<sup>1</sup>, so there is no equivalent of printf.

Function calls in Algol (60) would look the same as in **C**: `printf("%d->%d", X, Y);`

In Algol-68, however, a standard input/output library of functions was defined - which it calls transput. As these are polymorphic the argument list would have been passed as an array of elements, thus:

```
print((whole(X),"->",whole(Y));
```

(but then you could have got that off Wikipedia anyway)

[<sup>1</sup>]:(Although most implementations added it as a library function!)